# Initially Jquery Data table can not Hit the server side processing

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have Implemented jquery data table with server side processing in Dotnet MVC. The Problem I face that when I first time load the page the data table can't hit the server side unless i can click sort or change the number of display row or search something, if i do any of this thing then the related data show in data table nicely. but first time when page loaded no data is showing except the processing.. bar . i have 300 data at my table ..

**here is my controller ..**

```
public class IndicationController : Controller
{
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LoadData()
    {

        var draw = Request.Form.GetValues("draw").FirstOrDefault();
        var start = Request.Form.GetValues("start").FirstOrDefault();
        var length = Request.Form.GetValues("length").FirstOrDefault();

        var sortColumn =
            Request.Form.GetValues("columns[" + Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][column]").FirstOrDefault() +
                                   "][name]").FirstOrDefault();
        var sortColumnDir = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][dir]").FirstOrDefault();

        int pageSize = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
        int skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;
        int totalRecords = 0;

        using (DrugInformationContext dc = new DrugInformationContext())
        {
            dc.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; 
            var v = (from a in dc.Indications select a);

            if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumnDir)))
            {
                v = v.OrderBy(sortColumn + " " + sortColumnDir);
            }

            totalRecords = v.Count();
            var data = v.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
            return Json(
                new {draw = draw, recordsFiltered = totalRecords, recordsTotal = totalRecords, data = data},
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

**and here is my javascript**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#myTable").DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true, 
                
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Indication/LoadData",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "datatype": "json"
                },
                "columns": [
                        { "data": "IndicationName", "name": "IndicationName" }
                       
                ]
            });
        });

    </script>
```

is there anything that i'm missing or something wrong i have done ??

Comment: Shouldn't this be a GET request? I'm not seeing that you're sending any data with your POST request.

Comment: I've tried with Get request, bt same problem here... :(

Comment: how can i send data with post request... i am new in jquery, i have tried but can't do that ... :(